# Developing a Microsoft Teams Tab App inside of a DevContainer

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js, devcontainer

We want to develop a Microsoft Teams tab app inside a DevContainer without using the Teams Toolkit Plugin for VSCode. To accomplish this, we are setting up a Teams Tab App using `teamsapp.yml`, `teamsapp.local.yml`, and `manifest.json`. We are not using `launch.json` or `tasks.json` since these are specific to VSCode.

To set up a development environment that sideloads the app into Teams, we plan to use the `teamsfx` CLI. By running the commands `teamsfx account login m365`, `teamsfx provision --env local`, and `teamsfx deploy --env local`, the `teamsapp.local.yml` gets executed and we can publish a private app within our organization.

The challenge we're facing is that we cannot use these commands inside our DevContainer because they open a browser window for the login process. We have deactivated MFA to enable a non-interactive login process, as suggested in the documentation for the GitHub action [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/teamsfx-cli-action#configure-m365azure-credentials-as-github-secret). Additionally, we are providing credentials via the environment variables `M365_ACCOUNT_NAME`, `M365_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD`, and `M365_TENANT_ID`.

We read the documentation and issues of the TeamsFx repository and tried to solve the problem through trial and error. We also examined the documentation, issues, and code of the teamsfx-cli-action repository. It appears that developing Teams Apps in DevContainers is not yet widely supported, and it may be impossible with the current state of the TeamsFX-CLI, despite our initial expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To log in to M365 in a non-interactive process, you need to set `CI_ENABLED=true` in your environment variables, along with `M365_ACCOUNT_NAME`, `M365_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD`, and `M365_TENANT_ID`.
This will eliminate the need to run `teamsfx account login m365`, as `teamsfx provision` will automatically utilize the provided credentials.

I think `CI_ENABLED` flag has already been set by the teamsfx-cli-action in CD environment, so you did not find it in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. This solution works great.

The official documentation left me a bit confused. It would be helpful to have a section on CI with `teamsfx` in your [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/teamsfx-cli?pivots=version-two) or a link to your [GitHub Wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/teamsfx-cli?pivots=version-two). Unfortunately, I found it after asking this question. If you can guide me to a specific file or repository, I'd be happy to open a pull request.

Thanks again for your answer. 

Comment: (1/2) I need to make a revision to my previous comment. While this solution initially appeared effective due to its lack of requirement for interactive login, further examination reveals its shortcomings. Despite the Command Line Interface indicating success with a "Done: teamsApp/update was executed successfully" message in verbose mode, the app update process is flawed. Instead of updating the application properly, it merely deletes the branding information. Although the zip file is generated accurately,...

Comment: (2/2) ... the upload process seems ineffective, suggesting a potential issue with the CLI's upload functionality (if logged in non-interactive). I apologize for the inconvenience this has caused. If there's any way I can assist in identifying or resolving this issue, please don't hesitate to reach out. I am willing to provide any necessary support.